# Trying to figure out DOM and API ca;; with a simple page

Tags: html, dom

[image]

I was just fetching a pic and trying to add it as a background to a local page. I'm getting a below error. Please help me where I'm missing.

[image]

Comment: document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + response.url + ")" use this to add background image it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        fetch('https://images.pexels.com/photos/268533/pexels-photo-268533.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-268533.jpg&fm=jpg', {
        })
            .then((response) => response)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('Success:', result.url);
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + result.url + ")"
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```